In the Bekenstein bound, is $E$ and/or $R$ meant to be a strict upper bound or an average? (how to fit with position/momentum uncertainty?)
In the Bekenstein bound, $S\le2\pi R E/\hbar c$, where $E$ is the energy of the system (including mass energy etc.), and $R$ is the radius of a ball containing the system, which of these is strict (if either)?
What I mean is, is this about the case where the state is in the subspace of the Hilbert space, where the energy is strictly at most $E$, i.e. in the image of the projection operator $$1_{(-\infty,E]}(H)$$
where $1_{(-\infty,E]}$ is the indicator function for $(-\infty,E]$ and $H$ is the Hamiltonian?
Or, is it about the case where the the system is strictly inside the ball of radius $R$, with no, e.g. rapidly decaying but non-zero amplitude for some electron in the system being measured outside the ball?
It seems to me that it cannot be that both are meant to be strict, on account of the uncertainty principle, $$\Delta x \cdot \Delta p \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$$
and $E \ge pc$, from $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$, or $E \ge mc^2 + \frac{p^2}{2m}$ (if non-relativistic).
I've looked a bit at Bekenstein's "How does the entropy/information bound work?" , and in section III, he is talking about a thermal state, and so I suppose it is talking about an expected value of energy there? It also says in that same section:

"because the system’s Compton length must be smaller than its size R in order that the very notion of size be well defined"

which seems to suggest to me that maybe the support of the wavefunction in the position basis isn't supposed to be strictly within the ball of radius $R$, either? But I'm really not sure what the exact condition is supposed to be for the system to be "within a ball of radius $R$" (He seems to imply a particular answer, but I don't understand what it is.). Likewise I'm unclear on what the exact condition on the energy is supposed to be.
(I've also looked at other sources, but that's the one that seemed closest to providing me an answer.)
(I should perhaps mention that while I used the relativistic energy momentum equation above, I don't know how to do relativistic quantum mechanics, so if you can formulate your answer such that it doesn't require that I understand relativistic quantum mechanics in order to understand your answer, that would be a plus. But if a good answer needs to talk about relativistic things, there's no helping that I guess.)

Thank you Amit for for the edit you made; I appreciate the fixes! I'm about to make another small edit to fix a typo I made, but first wanted to express my appreciation for the fixes you made to the formatting and phrasing (especially because I don't know whether the edits show only the most recent edit, and I want your help to be recognized).
